# Android Google maps-v2 previous polyline not removing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

After trying all the previous answers on `StackOverflow` I am posting this answer.

I am showing live location of a driver and a path from that location to a specific destination. What i want is to remove the old polyline soon the live location of driver changes but it's not hapening and it's increasing number of polylines.

Here is the code where i am removing the polyline but it's not working.

```
private void drawRouteOnMap(GoogleMap map, List<LatLng> positions) {
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(12).color(Color.GREEN).geodesic(true);
    options.addAll(positions);

    if (polyline != null) {
        polyline.remove();
        Log.e("Old Poly", "Removed");
    }

    Log.e("Poly", "Added");
    polyline = mMap.addPolyline(options);
}
```

Comment: mMap.clear(); may help. It will clear the whole map

Comment: i have tried it but the problem is it is removing my markers also.

Comment: use a remove() call on polyline object.

Comment: @SagarNayak see the code above, i think i've done that

Comment: my bad. the log "Removed" is being printed? and the polyline is still there?

Comment: oh! i've checked that now and it's not been printed. i think the polyline is null maybe?

Comment: Seems somewhere in your code outside of `drawRouteOnMap()` the `polyline` is set to `null`.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko i've rechecked the whole code but `polyline` is not set to `null` anywhere

Comment: @JawadMalik May be recreated whole object, where `polyline` is field or something like that.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko i don't understand

Comment: @JawadMalik Something like: `public class Class1 { Polyline polyline; ... } ... Class1 class1 = new Class1();` - `polyline` field set to null for every `new Class1()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself. It is because that `function` was being called from another `call` due to which `polyline` instance was null. Solved it by saving `polyline` in `SharedPrefrence` and retrieving that value again on next call.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
// decleare it globally
List<Polyline> polylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();

private void drawRouteOnMap(GoogleMap map, List<LatLng> positions) {
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(12).color(Color.GREEN).geodesic(true);
    for(Polyline polyline: polylines){
      polyline.remove();
    }
    polylines.clear();

    for(LatLng latlng: positions){
        options.add(latlng);
        polylines.add(mMap.addPolyline(options);
    }
}
```